# flutter_local_notification zonedSchedule not working

Tags: flutter, flutter-local-notification

I would like to schedule daily notification on specific time (eg. 10:30PM daily). But I do not even receive one notification when I set the time to next minute of current time.
This is what I do:

```
static Future<void> scheduleNotification({
    int id = 0,
    String? title,
    String? body,
    String? payLoad,
    required DateTime scheduledNotificationDateTime,
  }) async {
    return _flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      id,
      title,
      body,
      _nextInstanceOfTime(scheduledNotificationDateTime),
      notificationDetails(),
      androidScheduleMode: AndroidScheduleMode.exactAllowWhileIdle,
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      matchDateTimeComponents: DateTimeComponents.time,
    );
  }

  static tz.TZDateTime _nextInstanceOfTime(DateTime time) {
    final tz.TZDateTime now = tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local);
    tz.TZDateTime scheduledDate = tz.TZDateTime(
        tz.local, now.year, now.month, now.day, time.hour, time.minute);
    if (scheduledDate.isBefore(now)) {
      scheduledDate = scheduledDate.add(const Duration(days: 1));
    }
    return scheduledDate;
  }
```

I have try to replace the `_nextInstanceOfTime(scheduledNotificationDateTime)` to `tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(const Duration(seconds: 1))` and I got notification after 1 second which my setup is correct to receive notification. Please help. Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have initialise the time zone database with `tz.initializeTimeZones()` but did not set the local location. So I added these line and now it is working already.

```
final timeZoneName = await FlutterTimezone.getLocalTimezone();
tz.setLocalLocation(tz.getLocation(timeZoneName));
```